# While adding ComponentGroup in Wix 3.6.2221.0 i get the error

Tags: wix, wix3.6

Error   19  The Directory element contains an unexpected child element 'ComponentGroup'.     Reporting\Directories.wxs  216 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [wix documentation for ComponentGroup](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_componentgroup.htm), the possible parent elements are [Fragment](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_fragment.htm) or [Product](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_product.htm). It is not allowed to put component groups directly under a directory element.

I typically put each component group in a separate wxs file like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>

        <DirectoryRef Id="someFolder">
            <Component Id="file1">
                <File Source="file1" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="file2">
                <File Source="file2" />
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>

        <ComponentGroup Id="mycomponentgroup">
            <ComponentRef Id="file1" />
            <ComponentRef Id="file2" />
        </ComponentGroup>

    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

And then I put a `ComponentGroupRef` under the relevant `Feature`.

Answer (score -1):

`ComponentGroup` needs to be placed into the `< Product>` tag, but not into the `< Directory>` tag. Pay more attention to the placement of your tags.

Comment: Great, guys. Thx to all.. my post answered to the current question. answered at first. if u cannot read properly, or cannot understand `quickly`, its not my problem. want great and nice answers? go to disigners. it is just a proger portal. have many free time to spend on such answers? ok, i glad for u. i ll earn ur money meanwhile. best wishes =)